# Shiny: input loses its reactivity if value is passed over a JavaScript function

Tags: r, shiny

The following inputText in ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
...
tags$input(class="form-control form-control-lg", type="text", value="Here", id="inputtext", style="margin-top:15px")),
...
)
```

reacts correctly when I type text manually in the input. In the server side, the function activated looks like this:

```
  wordsCandidates <- reactive({
    if (is.null(nGrams)) { return(NULL) }
    wordsCandidates <- predictWords(input$inputtext, nGrams(), numberCandidates = input$integer, ngramRange = 1:4)
    wordsCandidates
  })
```

`predictWords` delivers a set of predicted next words from the content of the input in the UI. I do not believe my problem lies in the function itself, as I get the expected output. My problem arises when I update the input using a JavaScript function associated with a button click. Like in this animated gif (please note that sometimes I update the input by clicking on the buttons (button's color changes with hover). After that I have to press the space key to make the predict function work):

[image: 1]]

The Javascript function updating my inputtext is:

```
function sendValueFromTab(el) {   
    var newWord = ($(el).attr("id"));
    var oldString = document.getElementById("inputtext").value;
    document.getElementById("inputtext").value = oldString + " " + newWord;
}
```

Does someone knows why this reactivity lose arises?

Comment: If you want Shiny to react, you need to send it a message (which you do when you press the space button). Look into adding a custom message from client to the server to your function: https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

Comment: `Shiny.onInputChange("inputtext", newString)` did the job thanks!!

Comment: Sweet! Happy to help